# Exactly how does one navigate through ubuntu's startup files?

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I understand that there is a switch from init.d to init in Ubuntu.  Init.d was fine for me, but I can see and appreciate the change.  I am also incredibly thankful that the config files are not foul XML, like launchd's are.  Good ideas.

However, using maverick, I still see an awful lot of stuff in init.d.  I had thought that upstart was the way forward.  I am certain that upstart + init.d is not as simple as either one alone.

So how do I determine the startup procedure, or where to look for files to control some server?

EDIT:  More to the point, I guess I'm asking how does the interaction between upstart and sysvinit work *today*? I am suspicious of the wiki, much of it seems to be from older versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how do I determine the startup procedure

Create file in /etc/init/

> or where to look for files to control some server?

In /etc/init/

Getting Started upstart: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

An article at http://www.linux.com/archive/articles/125977 discusses the transition.

If you don't find a services' control script in /etc/init.d, I assume you'll find it's equivalent(s) in /etc/event.d